# How can I improve eclipse code completion?

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, content-assist

Eclipse does not find the correct variable for code completion as shown below.

```
int i = 0;
f(xyz);    // f takes an int but eclipse won't fill it with i.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "Window" > "Preferences" > "Java" > "Editor" > "Content Assist", make sure "Fill method arguments and show guess arguments" is set and "Insert best guessed arguments" is selected.

---

*Edit:*

I tried this in my Eclipse (Version: Helios Service Release 1 - Build id: 20100917-0705):

```
public class BestGuessedParameter {
    static int xyz = 1;
    static void f(final int xyz) {
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int i = 0;
        f/*cursor here*/
    }
}
```

Right after I typed the `f`, I hit space and selected `f(xyz)`, Eclipse did supply `f(i)` with `i` highlighted and in a pop-down menu of `i` (highlighted), `xyz`, and `0`. `i` was the default.

I couldn't find any info on how Eclipse selects the "best guessed parameters" (I have no idea where to look in the Eclipse source).  I would guess that Eclipse "guesses" based on type, name, and visibility, and that Eclipse thinks there's a better match than your local variable. Perhaps if the local variable were closer in type and name, it would be a better match?

Comment: I have that selected, still doesn't do this.